# Stuck in compilation （substrate-node-template：make build ）

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, substrate

I followed the tutorial[enter link description here](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup#compiling-substrate) to this step，

```
 make build
 WASM_BUILD_TOOLCHAIN=nightly-2020-10-05 cargo build --release
       Compiling node-template-runtime v2.0.0 (/home/wangliqiu2021/CLionProjects/substrate-node-template/runtime)
 Building [=====================================================> ] 857/861: node-template-runtime(build)
```

Cargo has been executed for a long time(almost one+ hour) without ending,It seems to be stuck, does anyone know the reason？help me

OS：Ubuntu 20.04

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700 Eight-Core Processor

Comment: I guess there are around 900 dependencies. So it probably takes that long. I was doing the same yesterday. One of the final dependencies took around 14-15 mins alone which didn't seem rational. Not sure about the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.

`$CARGO_HOME/config.toml`:

```
[build]
target-dir = "target"
```

remove it.

Comment: Why would that slow it down? Removing it won't cause any problems I suppose because "target" is anyways the default. If you read some issue relating to it, please link it here.

Comment: Before moving it，I found the target directory is `~/target`. After i moved it, the target directory appears under the project directory.  @Mihir

Answer (score 2):

The compile is not stuck in compilation, it is just taking a while due to the 800+ dependencies. From @gnunicorn on [this github issue](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/89):

> Rust isn't particular quick with the compiling at the moment and opaque to the person in front, at this step (when compiling `node-template-runtime`) we are actually building the project twice: once natively and once in wasm. So at some step in between it appears as if nothing happens and that can take up to half the total build time – if the other part took e.g. 10minutes then this process might take another 10min without any indicator of process (other than the CPU pumping hard).

You are doing a release build (`cargo build --release`) which enables optimizations. For development purposes, a regular build or just a `cargo check` will be substantially faster.

Some comments in the linked GitHub issue mentioned that running a `cargo clean` and rebuilding helped speed up compile times, so you can try that as well.

Comment: build dependency 1 - 856 is fast, but stuck in 857 for a long time

Comment: @wangliqiu2021 yes, dependency number 857 (`node-template-runtime`) has a longer compilation process as explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

From your username. I think you are in China, same as me.

`node-template-runtime(build)` means you're compiling the runtime into a wasm file. During this, it might need a download (so try to use a VPN).

*The download only happened in 1.0.0 https://docs.rs/substrate-wasm-builder/1.0.0/substrate_wasm_builder/?search=*

---

Also, the wasm compiling will take a long time too (depend on your hardware).

In the 2016 MacBookPro, the whole compiling takes 30mins.

---

Moreover, there might be a bug in that `build.rs`. Sometimes I've to run `cargo clean`. If I interrupt the compiling while `node-template-runtime(build)`.

Comment: `During this, it might need a download (so try to use a VPN). `   download  what?

Comment: Probably some type of dependency

Comment: Download the wasm builder

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was, that the WASM runtime build expects to find the WASM files inside the local `target` directory.

If the build can't find the local WASM files in the `target` directory - it just hangs or deadlocks (e.g. [GitHub issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9113)).

I had to change the `target-dir` setting in `~/.cargo/config.toml`.

You can also override the global setting with a local env var:

```
CARGO_TARGET_DIR=target cargo build
```

Or you can use the cargo CLI flags:

```
cargo build --target-dir=target
```

Note that some of the `wasm-builder` based build scripts ignore the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` env variable (e.g. [wasm_project.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs#L437)).